# validation with different error classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 3 fields in my form. I would like to validate Name, Age with an error class and Total_score with another error class. This is a single form contains single id. How can I do that.

```
$('#form1').validate({
   rules: {
     'Name' : {
       required   : true
     },
     'Age'   : {
       required: true

     },
     'Total_score' : {
        required: true
     }
   },
   messages: {
     'Name' : {
       required: 'From date is required!'
     },
     'Age'   : {
       required: 'To date is required!'
     },
     'Total_score' : {
       required: 'Score is required!'
     }
   },
   errorClass: '?????',
   errorPlacement: function(err, element) {
   err.insertBefore(element);
   },
   submitHandler: function(form) {
   form.submit();
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
<input name="Name" data-errorclass="error-name"/>
```

then

```
$('#form1').validate({
    rules: {
        'Name' : {
            required   : true
        },
        'Age'   : {
            required: true

        },
        'Total_score' : {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        'Name' : {
            required: 'From date is required!'
        },
        'Age'   : {
            required: 'To date is required!'
        },
        'Total_score' : {
            required: 'From date is required!'
        }
    },
    errorPlacement: function(err, element) {
        err.addClass(element.data('errorclass'))
        err.insertBefore(element);
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uderW/)

Comment: Thanks Arun.I dont know, is it possible in rails erb. tried but still have no idea

Comment: @Sam what do you mean by in jQuery itself

Comment: i mean cant we add 2 error classes in js files? still i dont know any way to do something like above in rails